# Уместить изображение в DIV с сохранением пропорций IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Есть блок `div` фиксированного размера ***231x231***, в котором находятся картинка неизвестного размера.

***Как ограничить картинку, чтобы она не выходила за размеры этого `div`?***

Если высота больше ширины, то ограничить высоту, если ширина больше высоты, то ограничить ширину. Так же картинка должна быть по середине блока, если ее ширина больше ее высоты.

Все это должно работать на ***`IE7`***, в чем и заключается основная проблема.

```css
.gc {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  height: 287px;
  width: 241px
}

.ic {
  background-color: #212121;
  position: absolute;
  height: 231px;
  width: 231px;
  right: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px
}

.gi {
  height: 100%
}

.gn {
  background-color: #212121;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 36px;
  width: 231px;
  right: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  bottom: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="gc">
  <div class="ic">
    <a href="#"><img class="gi" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/callofduty/images/7/76/Call_of_Duty_Ghosts_PS3_cover_art.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130502141822" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="gn">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="gc">
  <div class="ic">
    <a href="#"><img class="gi" src="https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-hvb31m5nys/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/126/454/PS1-Crash_Bandicoot_3_Warped__18194.1487050006.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="gn">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="gc">
  <div class="ic">
    <a href="#"><img class="gi" src="https://static.stratege.ru/trophies/NPWR05636_00/ICON0.PNG" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="gn">Test</div>
</div>
```

[Что имеем на данным момент](http://jsfiddle.net/ghb1cwo2/5/)

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться, нахрена вам IE7?

Comment: Забейте на IE7 и вобще всё что старше 11 версии (мы иногда даже на 11 забиваем)

Comment: @andreymal устройство на котором это будет локально работать, аналог IE7

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, основная проблема - выравнивание картинки по вертикали. Для её решения можно использовать свойство табличной ячейки `vertical-align`.

```css
.thumb {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.thumb img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 213px;
  max-height: 213px;
  border: none;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #fff;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
}

.pic-cell {
  width: 231px;
  height: 231px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="pic-cell">
        <a href="#" class="thumb"><img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/callofduty/images/7/76/Call_of_Duty_Ghosts_PS3_cover_art.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130502141822" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="pic-cell">
        <a href="#" class="thumb"><img src="https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-hvb31m5nys/images/stencil/1280x1280/products/126/454/PS1-Crash_Bandicoot_3_Warped__18194.1487050006.jpg?c=2&imbypass=on" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td class="pic-cell">
        <a href="#" class="thumb"><img class="gi" src="https://static.stratege.ru/trophies/NPWR05636_00/ICON0.PNG" alt=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Для 7-го `IE` самое то...